# popBackStack not working when nested navigation inside BottomNavBar

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a Bottom Nav Bar containing 4 tabs at the bottom. Inside second tab , I am opening Search bar. I have a back button before the search icon to navigate back to previous screen.

How my Search works:

- type abc, it will open a list with 3 items
- Inside list, there is button to open another list if it has more than
  3 items.
- Now I click back button, it should go to the list with 3 items and again on pressing back button , should got to the first tab screen.

I am trying to handle this using `navcontroller.popbackstack()`

```
             SearchScreen(
                  backNavigation = {
                        viewModel.navigateBack()
                    },
                    enableBackButton = viewModel.navigateToPreviousList
```

but once reached to the list having 3 items on pressing  back button again, nothing happens. How to handle the back button so that it should navigate to HomeScreen.